# How to send a structure as data on UDP using SendBuffer?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

```
typedef struct
{
    char cStartByte;  // Set Cmd 0xB1
   int  iTotalBytes; 
   char cSeqNum;        // 0 to 99 repeating
   char cCommand;   //
   char cPrintCmd;  //
       float fData[8]
} CMD,*psCmdOut;
```

In the code tried many options with no success  what to put in ??? to sedn the above structure?

```
  UDPClient1->SendBuffer(EHost->Text,12000, ????);
```

Comment: How could we possible know ? What is `UDPClient1` ? What does `SendBuffer` does, exactly ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't send your structure as-is using a socket : you need to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) it. You need to create a common format for data exchange, usually an array of char [like this one](http://alkautsarpens.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/f44.jpg).

Code :

```
unsigned char* ToCharArray(psCmdOut s)
{
    unsigned char serial[12]; //32-bit arch
    serial[0] = s.cStartByte;
    /*etc.*/
    return serial;
}
```

You can cast your structure in a `(char*)` back and forth , but I would advise strongly against it : the implicit conversion hides subtleties like endianness, internal memory padding and alignment, which can blow your system in a unpredictable way.

Comment: This advice is wrong for this situation. You do not need to serialize the struct since it only contains POD values. You can pass the struct as-is to socket functions like `send()`.  In the case of Indy's `SendBuffer()` specifically, whether that is allowed or not depends on the Indy version.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your version of Indy.

In Indy 8 and 9, `SendBuffer()` has the following signture:

```
void __fastcall SendBuffer(String AHost, const int APort, void* ABuffer, const int AByteCount);
```

So you can do this:

```
CMD cmd;
// fill cmd as needed...
UDPClient1->SendBuffer(EHost->Text, 12000, &cmd, sizeof(cmd));
```

In Indy 10, `SendBuffer()` was changed to take a `TIdBytes` (dynamic array of bytes) instead:

```
void __fastcall SendBuffer(const String AHost, const TIdPort APort, const TIdBytes ABuffer);
```

So you cannot pass the struct pointer directly anymore.  However, Indy 10 has a `RawToBytes()` function to create a `TIdBytes` from a memory block, so you can do this instead:

```
CMD cmd;
// fill cmd as needed...
UDPClient1->SendBuffer(EHost->Text, 12000, RawToBytes(&cmd, sizeof(cmd)));
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. Could you complete it with the information how to receive the struct on the server side?

Comment: That depends on whether you are using `TIdUDPClient` or `TIdUDPServer` on the server side (yes, a `TIdUDPClient` can send to another `TIdUDPClient`). `TIdUDPClient` has `ReceiveBuffer()` methods that fill either a memory block or a `TIdBytes` depending on Indy version. `TIdUDPServer` has an `OnUDPRead` event that provides data using either a `TStream` or `TIdBytes` depending on Indy version. And Indy 10 has a `BytesToRaw()` function for copying a `TIdBytes` into a memory block.

Comment: First of: should it not be `sizeof(CMD)` instead of `sizeof(cmd)` ? I tried getting it to work with TIdUDPServer, however could not manage to. I opened a separate question in order not to go offtopic with this one. Maybe you can have a look: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088377/correctly-sending-and-receiving-a-struct-through-indy-udp).

Comment: `sizeof(a type)` and `sizeof(variable of that type)` return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

As the @Sam suggested:

> UDPClient1->SendBuffer(EHost->Text,12000,reinterpret_cast(&cmd_command));

But the length of the structure is also required. So it will be:

```
UDPClient1->SendBuffer(EHost->Text,12000,reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cmd_command), sizeof(cmd_command));
```

And also I think it will be better if you do packing of the structure by adding

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

This will give you the actual size of the structure. With this you will be able to send the complete structure. And while receiving on the other side, typecast it back to the same structure.

Comment: And consider endianness. And never add interaction into the struct.

Comment: Yes consider endianness also.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What do you mean by "never add interaction into the struct"? I didn't get that.

Comment: I meant to write "indirection"

Comment: You don't need the `reinterpret_cast`.  In versions of Indy where `SendBuffer()` accepts a pointer, the pointer is declared as `void*`, so you can pass `&cmd_command` without casting it.