# Correctly sending and receiving a struct through Indy UDP

Tags: c++, udp, indy

Consider the following minimal program using Borland 2007 and Indy UDP server and client:

```
struct DATA_PACKAGE
{
    int t;
    int x;
    int y;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   DATA_PACKAGE a;
   a.t = 3;
   a.x = 2;
   a.y = 1;
   Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("sent " + IntToStr(sizeof(DATA_PACKAGE)));
   Form1->UDPClient1->SendBuffer(server,port,RawToBytes(&a, sizeof(DATA_PACKAGE)));
}

void __fastcall TForm1::UDPServer1UDPRead(TObject *Sender, TBytes AData,
      TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    DATA_PACKAGE r;
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("received " + IntToStr(sizeof(AData)));
    BytesToRaw(AData, &r, sizeof(AData));
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(r.t) + " " + IntToStr(r.x) + " " + IntToStr(r.y));
}
```

output:

```
sent 12
received 4
3 4717901 0
```

First of all, why is it sending 12, but only receiving 4 bytes?

Secondly what happends to x and y ?

When I change the datatype of t,x,y to short, I get:

```
sent 6 
received 4 
3 2 0
```

looking around I found pointers that the packing (and possibly the endianness?) of the struct is of importance, I could however not find a clear guide how design it properly.

Comment: The data received depends on another side of UDP communication. If another side works like echo server, you may expect to receive the same data as send before. It is difficult to see what is the problem without knowing how another side is working.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean the server side? This program is (for testing purposes) sending data to itself, as it is Client and Server in one.

Comment: `sizeof(TBytes)` looks suspicious. What is `TBytes`? If this it some class, sizeof may give the size of the class itself, and not the data it contains.

Comment: `TBytes` is a typedef for `DyanmicArray<Byte>`, ie a Delphi-style dynamic array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TBytes` is a dynamic array of bytes, it is implemented by the RTL as a pointer, which is why `sizeof(AData)` is returning 4.  Do not use `sizeof(AData)`, use the `AData.Length` property instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::UDPServer1UDPRead(TObject *Sender, TBytes AData,
      TIdSocketHandle *ABinding)
{
    DATA_PACKAGE r;
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("received " + IntToStr(AData.Length));
    BytesToRaw(AData, &r, AData.Length);
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(IntToStr(r.t) + " " + IntToStr(r.x) + " " + IntToStr(r.y));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was issue. Just for clarification: if my struct contains a dynamic object (like AnsiString or a vector) the transaction won't work this way, right?

Comment: That is correct.  You cannot send pointers over the socket, you have to serialize the data into a flattened format.